# Add geom_density by group, on a categorical X variable (numeric classes)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to r and was hoping for help with trying to overlay a line onto a grouped bar chart I made in ggplot.  My initial plot is generated from a table I created (PlotData3) that includes three columns, which I assign to the x value, the grouping, and y value, and chart as follows:

```
PlotData3 <- structure(list(AllCanc.Risk.Group = c(">200", "10-19", "100-199",
"20-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59", "60-69", "70-79", "80-89",
"90-99", ">200", "10-19", "100-199", "20-29", "30-39", "40-49",
"50-59", "60-69", "70-79", "80-89", "90-99", ">200", "10-19",
"100-199", "20-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59", "60-69", "70-79",
"80-89", "90-99"), variable = c("US", "US", "US", "US", "US",
"US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT",
"AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW",
"SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW"), value = c(0.00664835861606374,
2.44355372567952, 0.130822020220507, 15.4709366277295, 32.4518264644337,
32.2667953215994, 13.3192561678316, 2.7733516677064, 0.675660976523301,
0.332458575790359, 0.128690093869533, 0.211223625656804, 1e-06,
2.43781818419616, 1e-06, 4.09352040466, 28.1323875136102, 37.2534225747702,
19.8154572533735, 4.55373287077757, 1.58548507865301, 1.91695249430252,
1e-06, 1e-06, 1e-06, 23.3036724323788, 52.5797733223538, 20.7005565950558,
2.56960027700278, 0.522043694524534, 0.177713854060081, 1e-06,
0.146639824624097)), row.names = c(NA, -33L), .Names = c("AllCanc.Risk.Group",
"variable", "value"), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
fill_palette <-c("darkorange", "dimgray", "dodgerblue")
ggplot(PlotData3, aes(x=factor(AllCanc.Risk.Group), y=value)) +   ###send data to ggplot
  geom_rect(data=PlotData3, aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=1.5, ymin=-Inf, ymax=+Inf), fill='gray80', alpha=0.02)+    ##Create background to help visualiztion
  geom_rect(data=PlotData3, aes(xmin=1.5, xmax=2.5, ymin=-Inf, ymax=+Inf), fill='white', alpha=0.02)+
  geom_rect(data=PlotData3, aes(xmin=2.5, xmax=3.5, ymin=-Inf, ymax=+Inf), fill='gray80', alpha=0.02)+
  geom_rect(data=PlotData3, aes(xmin=3.5, xmax=4.5, ymin=-Inf, ymax=+Inf), fill='white', alpha=0.02)+
  geom_rect(data=PlotData3, aes(xmin=4.5, xmax=5.5, ymin=-Inf, ymax=+Inf), fill='gray80', alpha=0.02)+
  geom_rect(data=PlotData3, aes(xmin=5.5, xmax=6.5, ymin=-Inf, ymax=+Inf), fill='white', alpha=0.02)+
  geom_rect(data=PlotData3, aes(xmin=6.5, xmax=7.5, ymin=-Inf, ymax=+Inf), fill='gray80', alpha=0.02)+
  geom_rect(data=PlotData3, aes(xmin=7.5, xmax=8.5, ymin=-Inf, ymax=+Inf), fill='white', alpha=0.02)+
  geom_rect(data=PlotData3, aes(xmin=8.5, xmax=9.5, ymin=-Inf, ymax=+Inf), fill='gray80', alpha=0.02)+
  geom_rect(data=PlotData3, aes(xmin=9.5, xmax=10.5, ymin=-Inf, ymax=+Inf), fill='white', alpha=0.02)+
  geom_rect(data=PlotData3, aes(xmin=10.5, xmax=11.5, ymin=-Inf, ymax=+Inf), fill='gray80', alpha=0.02)+
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity",aes(fill=factor(variable))) +     # create bar chart, dodge for a clustered chart
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 60)) +     # axis limits
  xlab("All Cancer Risk Group\n (per million)") + ylab("Percent of Residents") +  # axis lables
  scale_fill_manual(name="", values=fill_palette) +  #legend title, fill
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=8))+    #axis font
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("<10", "10-19", "20-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59", "60-69", "70-79","80-89", "90-99","100-199",">200"))+  #order the x label correctly
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90))+   #adjust the x lable to vertical
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=10))+    #adjust the axis/legend fonts
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=10))+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())+
  geom_density(data = PlotData3, x = factor(AllCanc.Risk.Group), y = value, fill = variable, position = stack)
```

I can produce the resulting chart

[image]

I'd like to overlay density lines to better visualize the difference in the distribution between the two groups.  I've tried different combinations of geom_density(), but keep getting the same error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found
```

Am I missing something?

Here's my data table

the closest I got was adding:

```
geom_density(stat="identity", fill=NA)
```

which didn't error but gave me a result that looks like this (vertical lines)
[image]

I also tried:

```
 geom_density(data=PlotData3, aes(x=AllCanc.Risk.Group, group=variable, fill=NA))
```

and

```
geom_density(data=PlotData3, aes(x=AllCanc.Risk.Group, y=value, group=variable, fill=NA))
```

Which gave the

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found

Comment: You need to add the data itself for us to answer the question. Also, what `geom_density()` calls have you tried?

Comment: @black_sheep07 thanks, I edited the post to add the data and what I've tried.

Comment: Use `dput` to provide a table that we can use easily instead of just the output

Comment: @black_sheep07 Edited my code above to include the data (sorry, new to r and new to stack overflow)

Comment: I don't think you're gaining anything from `geom_density` here, although your last example should work if you just add `stat = "identity"`.  You could also just use `geom_line` with the `group` aesthetic set to your grouping variable (my guess is you'll want to add some color, as well, to match the bar fill).

Comment: black_sheep07 and @aosmith  Thank you guys so much, that worked!  Added    `geom_density(data=PlotData3, aes(x=AllCanc.Risk.Group, y=value, group=variable, fill=variable, color=variable), stat="identity", alpha=0)`

Comment: Just want to thank for the background-code to help visualization!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `fill = NA`. You are currently choosing to fill it with something that does not exist. Instead choose to fill it with the `variable` that contains `AT`, `SW`, and `US`.

Instead, use `geom_density(aes(x = AllCanc.Risk.Group, y = value, fill = factor(variable), position = "stack", stat = "identity"))`

Also consider adding some `alpha` to make the different layers of the density plot see-through.

Comment: Hmm, that then gave me    "Error in do.call("layer", list(mapping = mapping, data = data, stat = stat,  : 
  object 'AllCanc.Risk.Group' not found"

Comment: To clarify, I just added the geom_density line at the end of code, and re-ran the whole code.

Comment: It looks like it's still having trouble finding the x variable.  I get:  Error in factor(AllCanc.Risk.Group) : 
  object 'AllCanc.Risk.Group' not found

Comment: Did you forget to put your mapping variables inside `aes`?